# AWS DynamoDB Scan Operation Works w/ Class Level Scan, but not Document Writer Scan

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

The following params return the expected result in a scan operation using `dynamoDB.scan(params, function);`

```
const dynamoDB = new AWS::DynamoDB();
let params = {
    TableName: ACCOUNT_USAGE_TABLE,
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ":start_date": {
            S: new Date(event.start_date).toISOString(),
        },
        ":end_date": {
            S: new Date(event.end_date).toISOString()
        }
    },
    ExpressionAttributeNames: {
        "#usage_date": "date",
    },
    FilterExpression: "#usage_date BETWEEN :start_date AND :end_date",
    ExclusiveStartKey: event.LastEvaluatedKey
};
```

But the preceding params fail with when using the `dynamoDB.documentClient.scan(params, function)` with,

`ValidationException: Invalid FilterExpression: Incorrect operand type for operator or function; operator or function: BETWEEN, operand type: M`

Any ideas as to why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course, the answer was staring me directly in the face.
In case anybody else runs into it and doesn't see it immediately.

The DynamoDB Document Client in javascript uses javascript types and therefore saw the `start_date` and `end_date` objects (`[object]`) a.k.a `operand type: M`.

All I had to do is change the `ExpressionAttributeValues` to

```
ExpressionAttributeValues: {
    ":start_date": new Date(event.start_date).toISOString(),
    ":end_date": new Date(event.end_date).toISOString()
},
```

And voilà, it works.

Answer (score 0):

This code below worked for my scenario, to query between two dates. The error I got is **"Invalid FilterExpression: Incorrect operand type for operator or function; operator or function: BETWEEN, operand type: M".**

```
let params = {
TableName: tableName,
ProjectionExpression:"Id, FirstName, LastName, #ProcessedFlag, #CreatedTimeStamp",
FilterExpression: '#CreatedTimeStamp BETWEEN :fromDateTime AND :toDateTime AND #ProcessedFlag = :flag',
ExpressionAttributeNames: {
  '#ProcessedFlag': processedFlagName,
  '#CreatedTimeStamp': createdTimeStampName,
},
ExpressionAttributeValues: {
  ':flag' : flag,
  ':fromDateTime' : new Date(fromDateTime).toISOString() ,
  ':toDateTime' : new Date(toDateTime).toISOString(),
}
```

};

Comment: I'd suggest adding details about what you changed so your original non-working answer worked. Without that info, this doesn't qualify as an answer.