# How can I add date range in filter expression in dynamodb

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am using `dynamodb` and the table `Devices` partition key is `id`, sort key is `type`.

There is a `timestamp` field whose value is `'2020-07-04T04:40:09.970Z'`.

Below is the query parameter I sent to the table.

```
{
      TableName: 'Devices',
      ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ':transaction': 'transaction',
        ':deviceUuid': '6e0b772f-a77a-4081-ab11-04c5a1f7682b',
        ':timestamp_gt': { S: '2020-06-04T04:48:16.212Z' },
        ':timestamp_lt': { S: '2020-07-04T04:48:16.332Z' }
      },
      KeyConditionExpression: 'id = :deviceUuid AND begins_with(#type, :transaction)',
      ExpressionAttributeNames: { '#type': 'type', '#timestamp': 'timestamp' },
      Limit: 20,
      ScanIndexForward: false,
      FilterExpression: '((#timestamp < :timestamp_lt) AND (#timestamp > :timestamp_gt))'
    }
```

but I got an error:
`ValidationException: Invalid FilterExpression: Incorrect operand type for operator or function; operator or function: <, operand type: M`

I think the error means I can't use `<` and `>` operators on type `M`. And `M` means object or map. But for my query, the `timestamp` is just a string and all my items also have string value for this field. Why it complains about type M?

Answer (score 0):

Normally when using 2 expressions you can use `BETWEEN` as an [operand](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.OperatorsAndFunctions.html).

```
{
      TableName: 'Devices',
      ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ':transaction': 'transaction',
        ':deviceUuid': '6e0b772f-a77a-4081-ab11-04c5a1f7682b',
        ':timestamp_gt': { S: '2020-06-04T04:48:16.212Z' },
        ':timestamp_lt': { S: '2020-07-04T04:48:16.332Z' }
      },
      KeyConditionExpression: 'id = :deviceUuid AND begins_with(#type, :transaction)',
      ExpressionAttributeNames: { '#type': 'type', '#timestamp': 'timestamp' },
      Limit: 20,
      ScanIndexForward: false,
      FilterExpression: '(#timestamp BETWEEN :timestamp_lt AND :timestamp_gt)'
    }
```

Comment: Regarding the error if you're using javascript this might be relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52976302/aws-dynamodb-scan-operation-works-w-class-level-scan-but-not-document-writer-s